# Error while processing references for EJB-in-WAR: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, nullpointerexception, websphere

I have an application which has 5 EARs. One of those includes the frontend (AppFE.ear) which is actually a WAR incapsulated in an EAR, and it uses JSF with Primefaces.

Two ears are for DataModel/DataAccess (App_DataModel, App_DataAccess), and other two EARs are for services/EJB (App_Services, App_EJB).

I'm not able to start the frontend EAR. It says:

```
Unable to start: AppFE_EAR using: WebSphere:name=ApplicationManager,process=server1,platform=proxy,node=Backslash-PCNode03,version=8.0.0.9,type=ApplicationManager,mbeanIdentifier=ApplicationManager,cell=Backslash-PCNode03Cell,spec=1.0 exception is: javax.management.MBeanException: Exception thrown in RequiredModelMBean while trying to invoke operation startApplication
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1195)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:999)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:847)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:783)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1335)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1228)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.AppManagementImpl._startApplication(AppManagementImpl.java:1481)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.AppManagementImpl.startApplication(AppManagementImpl.java:1370)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.AppManagementImpl.startApplication(AppManagementImpl.java:1319)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:69)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor37.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:272)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean$4.run(RequiredModelMBean.java:1152)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:298)
    at com.ibm.oti.security.CheckedAccessControlContext.securityCheck(CheckedAccessControlContext.java:30)
    at sun.misc.JavaSecurityAccessWrapper.doIntersectionPrivilege(JavaSecurityAccessWrapper.java:41)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1146)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:999)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:847)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:783)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1335)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1228)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.remote.AdminServiceForwarder.invoke(AdminServiceForwarder.java:346)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1466)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:86)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1307)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1399)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:830)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi._RMIConnectionImpl_Tie.invoke(_RMIConnectionImpl_Tie.java:751)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi._RMIConnectionImpl_Tie._invoke(_RMIConnectionImpl_Tie.java:158)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ServerDelegate.dispatchInvokeHandler(ServerDelegate.java:678)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ServerDelegate.dispatch(ServerDelegate.java:525)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.ORB.process(ORB.java:616)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ORB.process(ORB.java:1581)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.Connection.doRequestWork(Connection.java:3160)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.Connection.doWork(Connection.java:3030)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.WorkUnitImpl.doWork(WorkUnitImpl.java:64)
    at com.ibm.ejs.oa.pool.PooledThread.run(ThreadPool.java:118)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1702)
Caused by: com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeWarning: Error while processing references for EJB-in-WAR: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.EJBContainerImpl.createNestedModuleMetaData(EJBContainerImpl.java:3434)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.EJBContainerImpl.createNestedModuleMetaData(EJBContainerImpl.java:726)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.MetaDataMgrImpl.createNestedModuleMetaData(MetaDataMgrImpl.java:564)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:633)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:967)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:771)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplicationDynamically(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1362)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2163)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:389)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:332)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:119)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$1.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:607)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5468)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5594)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:621)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:565)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1252)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:69)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor37.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:272)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean$4.run(RequiredModelMBean.java:1152)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:298)
    at com.ibm.oti.security.CheckedAccessControlContext.securityCheck(CheckedAccessControlContext.java:30)
    at sun.misc.JavaSecurityAccessWrapper.doIntersectionPrivilege(JavaSecurityAccessWrapper.java:41)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1146)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.EJBContainerImpl.createNestedModuleMetaData(EJBContainerImpl.java:3422)
    ... 78 more
```

My web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
    <display-name>Monitor - WAR</display-name>


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>-1</load-on-startup>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <async-supported>false</async-supported>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>PNG</extension>
        <mime-type>image/x-png</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.CLIENT_SIDE_VALIDATION</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
</web-app>
```

I searched and found a thread in which a user said that adding the `metadata-complete="true"` attribute to the `web-app` node in the `web.xml` file solved the issue. It solves the issue, but for some reason JSF is not working with that property. I mean that JSF pages are not calling the controller anymore (I checked managedbeans names and they are correct, seems it isn't reading annotations anymore).

I'm using WebSphere 8.0.0.9 (latest fixpack).

Did anyone face this before?

Comment: You need to provide information about you EJB interfaces (local/remote) and sample definition of your EJB resource reference. You are probably trying to use local interfaces or have incorrect reference.

Comment: @Gas Thank you for your comment. The frontend EAR doesn't have EJBs, it just has remote lookups to EJBs contained in the other EAR. What do you mean by "EJB resource reference"? Anyway, this issue came up after upgrading Websphere to 8.0.0.9, before that we had Websphere 8.0.0.1 and everything worked fine. Could the issue be related with the upgrade?

Comment: If your frontend is calling EJB it either needs to use`@EJB` annotation or `InitialContext` to find EJBs. If you are sure that it was working in 8.0.0.1 and the only thing you've changed is WebSphere fixpack, then I'd suggest to try to reinstall your applications and if it doesn't help create PMR in IBM support.

Comment: @Gas I use `InitialContext` like `InitialContext context = new InitialContext(); ejb = context.lookup(remoteInterfaceName);`. Yes, I'm sure it worked, I started this project a month ago and till now everything worked without issue. It seems that installing the latest fixpack to solve a lot of WebSphere issues (OutOfMemoryErrors, and other things) caused this error. I'll try with the IBM support then. Thank you!

Comment: `metadata-complete="true"` indicates to the runtime that the web.xml or other config-file contains all the information necessary to deploy the application. The problem this creates is that annotation-support classes are not scanned during deployment